# Does OptimisticLockException occurs before hitting physical DB layer?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc, orm, optimistic-locking

Say that we are using Hibernate as a JPA implementation and as you all know it has a cache mechanism called first-level-cache.

Is OptimisticLockException is thrown from this cache layer or does it really hits the DB and sees that the version of that row has changed also in DB and then the exception is thrown?

Comment: why not look in the LOG of the JPA provider you use?

Comment: Since I don't have a code that throws optimisticlockexception by now then THERE IS NO LOG!